# PCA using princomp in MATLAB (for face recognition)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, gpgpu, face-recognition, pca

I'm trying to do dimensionality reduction using [MATLAB's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB) `princomp`, but I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

Here is the my code just for testing, but I'm not sure that I'm doing projection right:

```
A = rand(4,3)
AMean = mean(A)
[n m] = size(A)
Ac = (A - repmat(AMean,[n 1]))
pc = princomp(A)
k = 2; %Number of first principal components
A_pca = Ac * pc(1:k,:)'  %Not sure I'm doing projection right
reconstructedA = A_pca * pc(1:k,:)
error = reconstructedA- Ac
```

And my code for face recognition using ORL dataset:

```
%load orl_data 400x768 double matrix (400 images 768 features)
%make labels
orl_label = [];
for i = 1:40
    orl_label = [orl_label;ones(10,1)*i];
end

n = size(orl_data,1);
k = randperm(n);
s = round(0.25*n); %Take 25% for train

%Raw pixels
%Split on test and train sets
data_tr = orl_data(k(1:s),:);
label_tr = orl_label(k(1:s),:);
data_te = orl_data(k(s+1:end),:);
label_te = orl_label(k(s+1:end),:);

tic
[nn_ind, estimated_label] = EuclDistClassifier(data_tr,label_tr,data_te);
toc

rate = sum(estimated_label == label_te)/size(label_te,1)

%Using PCA
tic
pc = princomp(data_tr);
toc

mean_face = mean(data_tr);
pc_n = 100;
f_pc = pc(1:pc_n,:)';
data_pca_tr = (data_tr - repmat(mean_face, [s,1])) * f_pc;
data_pca_te = (data_te - repmat(mean_face, [n-s,1])) * f_pc;

tic
[nn_ind, estimated_label] = EuclDistClassifier(data_pca_tr,label_tr,data_pca_te);
toc

rate = sum(estimated_label == label_te)/size(label_te,1)
```

If I choose enough principal components it gives me equal recognition rates. If I use a small number of [principal components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (PCA) then the rate using PCA is poorer.

Here are some questions:

1. Is `princomp` function the best way to calculate first **k** principal components using MATLAB?
2. Using PCA projected features vs raw features don't give extra accuracy, but only smaller features vector size? (faster to compare feature vectors).
3. How to automatically choose min **k** (number of principal components) that give the same accuracy vs raw feature vector?
4. What if I have very big set of samples can I use only subset of them with comparable accuracy? Or can I compute PCA on some set and later "add" some other set (I don't want to recompute pca for set1+set2, but somehow iteratively add information from set2 to existing PCA from set1)?

I also tried the GPU version simply using `gpuArray`:

```
%Test using GPU
tic
A_cpu = rand(30000,32*24);
A = gpuArray(A_cpu);
AMean = mean(A);
[n m] = size(A)
pc = princomp(A);
k = 100;
A_pca = (A - repmat(AMean,[n 1])) * pc(1:k,:)';
A_pca_cpu = gather(A_pca);
toc
clear;

tic
A = rand(30000,32*24);
AMean = mean(A);
[n m] = size(A)
pc = princomp(A);
k = 100;
A_pca = (A - repmat(AMean,[n 1])) * pc(1:k,:)';
toc
clear;
```

It is working faster, but it's not suitable for big matrices. Maybe I'm wrong?

If I use a big matrix, it gives me:

> Error using gpuArray  Out of memory on device.

Answer (score 1):

"Is princomp function the best way to calculate first k principal components using MATLAB?"

It's computing a full SVD, so it will be slow on large datasets. You can speed this up significantly by specifying the number of dimensions you need at the start and computing a partial svd. The matlab functions for a partial svd is `svds`.

If svds' not fast enough for you there's a more modern implementation here:

http://cims.nyu.edu/~tygert/software.html (matlab version: http://code.google.com/p/framelet-mri/source/browse/pca.m )

(cf the paper describing the algorithm http://cims.nyu.edu/~tygert/blanczos.pdf )

You can control the error of your approximation by increasing the number of singular vectors computed, there's precise bounds on that in the linked paper. Here's an example:

```
>> A = rand(40,30); %random rank-30 matrix
>> [U,S,V] = pca(A,2); %compute a rank-2 approximation to A
>> norm(A-U*S*V',2)/norm(A,2) %relative error               

ans =

    0.1636

>> [U,S,V] = pca(A,25); %compute a rank-25 approximation to A
>> norm(A-U*S*V',2)/norm(A,2) %relative error                 

ans =

    0.0410
```

When you have large data and a sparse matrix computing a full SVD is often impossible since the factors will never be sparse. In this case you must compute a partial SVD to fit within memory. Example:

```
>> A = sprandn(5000,5000,10000);
>> tic;[U,S,V]=pca(A,2);toc;
no pivots
Elapsed time is 124.282113 seconds.
>> tic;[U,S,V]=svd(A);toc;   
??? Error using ==> svd
Use svds for sparse singular values and vectors.

>> tic;[U,S,V]=princomp(A);toc;
??? Error using ==> svd
Use svds for sparse singular values and vectors.

Error in ==> princomp at 86
    [U,sigma,coeff] = svd(x0,econFlag); % put in 1/sqrt(n-1) later

>> tic;pc=princomp(A);toc;     
??? Error using ==> eig
Use eigs for sparse eigenvalues and vectors.

Error in ==> princomp at 69
        [coeff,~] = eig(x0'*x0);
```

Comment: What is the memory consumption of these methods?

Comment: For a full SVD on an MxN matrix (ie using "princomp" or "svd") you will need to store dense matrices U and V, so 2*M*N. This is prohibitive when the input data is large (and thus being stored in a sparse matrix). Using svds or pca.m only requires that you store k*max(M,N) where k is the number of dimensions you need. If your data is really big, you can use the PCA implementation in Mahout (which is just an implementation of the paper linked in my answer) https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/math/ssvd/SequentialOutOfCoreSvd.html